# Problem on install

Tags: magento-1.9, upgrade

I uninstalled my Magento site, deleted all site files and dropped all tables from database, this install process went fine (version 1.8), but I wanted to move to 1.9 and could not upgrade via /downloader/

On new install I get the following error

```
a:5:{i:0;s:98:"Missing locale file '/www/domain.com/lib/Zend/Locale/Data/az_AZ.xml' for 'az_AZ' locale.";i:1;s:3617:"#0 /www/domain.com/lib/Zend/Locale/Data.php(231): Zend_Locale_Data::_findRoute('az_AZ', '/ldml/localeDis...', 'type', false, Array)
#1 /www/domain.com/lib/Zend/Locale/Data.php(955): Zend_Locale_Data::_getFile('az_AZ', '/ldml/localeDis...', 'type')
#2 /www/domain.com/lib/Zend/Locale.php(668): Zend_Locale_Data::getContent('az_AZ', 'language', 'az')
#3 /www/domain.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Locale.php(250): Zend_Locale::getTranslation('az', 'language', 'az_AZ')
#4 /www/domain.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Locale.php(223): Mage_Core_Model_Locale->_getOptionLocales(true)
#5 /www/domain.com/app/code/core/Mage/Install/Block/Locale.php(92): Mage_Core_Model_Locale->getTranslatedOptionLocales()
#6 /www/domain.com/app/design/install/default/default/template/install/locale.phtml(46): Mage_Install_Block_Locale->getLocaleSelect()
#7 /www/domain.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/www/domain...')
#8 /www/domain.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('install/default...')
#9 /www/domain.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#10 /www/domain.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#11 /www/domain.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Text/List.php(43): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#12 /www/domain.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Core_Block_Text_List->_toHtml()
#13 /www/domain.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(637): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#14 /www/domain.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(581): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('content', true)
#15 /www/domain.com/app/design/install/default/default/template/page.phtml(98): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('content')
#16 /www/domain.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/www/domain...')
#17 /www/domain.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('install/default...')
#18 /www/domain.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#19 /www/domain.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#20 /www/domain.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(555): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#21 /www/domain.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(390): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->getOutput()
#22 /www/domain.com/app/code/core/Mage/Install/controllers/WizardController.php(154): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->renderLayout()
#23 /www/domain.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Install_WizardController->localeAction()
#24 /www/domain.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('locale')
#25 /www/domain.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#26 /www/domain.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#27 /www/domain.com/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#28 /www/domain.com/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#29 {main}";s:3:"url";s:33:"/index.php/install/wizard/locale/";s:11:"script_name";s:10:"/index.php";s:4:"skin";s:7:"default";}
```

I have created the missing file using a similar file in the same directory and this process repeats about 8 times, where I have created 8 new XML files for different locals

After which I get to the timezone selection, and this drop-down is empty, so I `Inspect Element` and edit the select with the option `America/Chicago`

After this, I get to the database credentials and fill that in, where it crashes during the `create and populate` of the database (I get over 200 tables created).

Now Magento is showing a white page, I leave this page and go to index, another white page

I have tried this two times with file transfer and once with the `downloader.php` script available from the Magento site

I have created other 1.9 installs (I looked in their `/lib/Zend/Locale/Data/` folder and the files I had to create this time were missing there as well without my needing to make them), after the release date provided on the Magento site, so I assume the files should be good, and if they weren't I would expect to see more questions on SO or other sites with the same problem

**Server**

Apache on Ubuntu

all required modules installed per Magento server check file (same server I have installed other Magento 1.9 sites on and this original 1.8 on without prior issue)

I have made sure that the folders needing write permission have them

APC caching is enabled on the server, but has been disabled via .htaccess on the site

**end result**

What I ended up doing was deleting out the folder and recreating it, there may have been some hidden files or something preventing it, not sure

Comment: Why don't you simply upgrade by copying the files into your application? It is much simpler

Comment: its a beta site, not production, so I wanted to just have a fresh install of the site, with no lingering files that weren't in use if possible

Comment: Why wouldn't you simple install a new version of Magento then?

Comment: I was trying to install a new version

Answer (score 1):

I would download Magento and copy the files into your application rather than trying to use connect.

```
wget http://www.magentocommerce.com/downloads/assets/1.9.1.0/magento-1.9.1.0.tar.gz -P /home/folder/
cd /home/folder
tar xvfz magento-1.9.1.0.tar.gz
rsync -avz /home/folder/magento/ /path/to/your/devsite/
```

The visit your dev site and you will see that it has been upgraded

Comment: Will give it a shot and see what happens. thanks

Comment: What I ended up doing was deleting out the folder and recreating it, there may have been some hidden files or something preventing it, not sure